# HTML background issues with sizing

Tags: css, html

I have a very basic site with a left nav bar and a larger content area on the right. They each have different backgrounds.

I want both the content and navbar to be the same height and to maintain their backgrounds. I wasn't sure how to do this, so I put them both in a div and set its background to that of the navigation bar. When the content expands, it pushes the containing div and shows the correct background on the left:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ngey/3/embedded/result/

When the navigation is bigger than the content, however, the background is wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ngey/2/embedded/result/

What's the correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Also, on a side note, why does the containing div have a height of 0px even when the divs inside of it have height unless I set the containing div to float left?

edit:

To clarify, I want:

- Page as long as content
- Navigation bar as long as page
- Content as long as page
- Content and navigation maintain background colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you've discovered the near-impossibility of equal-height columns in CSS. There are a few hackish solutions out there, but the simplest? [Faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Simply make a 1000px wide, 1px tall image, and repeat it vertically on the background `div`. Make the first 100px blue, and the next 900px green. No one will know the difference!

```
#background { background: url(file.png) repeat-y; }
```

[**More techniques**](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) (that are generally more trouble than they're worth).

---

To answer your second question: floated elements will not add height to the parent (by default). To resolve this, simply set `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` on the wrapper `div` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ngey/4/embedded/result/)):

```
#wrapper { background:black; overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: I guess I'll use that solution for now, but I was hoping for something that would allow for more than just solid colors. Though it's what I need now, I would still like to know for later. Also, what I meant about the background div is that it had 0 height until I added float:left.

Comment: @Walkerneo, Oh, same deal. Drop the float: left and replace with overflow: hidden (see jsfiddle.net/8Ngey/5/embedded/result). See updated answer for a post to more techniques. Honestly, though, it's such a pain I highly advocate tables. (Though there's some out there who'd shoot me for saying such a thing.)